# Is the question whether the value of a given definite integral has a closed-form decideable?

Tags: calculus, integration, closed-form, decision-theory

Suppose, we have a definite convergent integral (possibly improper) with an elementary function as an integrand.

> Is there an algorithm deciding whether the value of the integral has a closed-form expression ?

Such an algorithm would be similar to the Risch-algorithm. The reason, why I have some hope that such an algorithm exists is that some definite integrals can be calculated (for example with the contour-integration-method), although no closed-form antiderivate exists.